# Calling class methods using dynamic string + arguments failing typescript compiler

Tags: typescript

See the minimal [example linked here and provided below](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=42&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#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).

I am having trouble figuring out how to define my interfaces such that the typescript compiler does not fail.  In the example I get the error:

```
Argument of type 'Method1Props | Method2Props | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Method1Props & Method2Props'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Method1Props & Method2Props'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Method1Props'.(2345)
```

I'm not really understanding my problem. Method2Call never has an `undefined` props and Method1Call allows for `undefined` props so it's unclear to me what this error message is referring to. Are there any typescript experts who might know how to fix this?

Provided minimal example:

```
interface Method1Props {
  abc: string
}

interface Method1Call {
  methodName: "method1",
  methodProps?: Method1Props
}

interface Method2Props {
  def: string
}

interface Method2Call {
  methodName: "method2",
  methodProps: Method2Props
}

type MethodCall = Method1Call | Method2Call

class TestCaller {
  method1(props?: Method1Props) {
    console.log("called method1 with " + props);
  }

  method2(props: Method2Props) {
    console.log("called method2 with " + props);
  }
}

function callTestCallerWithDynamicParam(someArgs: MethodCall) {
  new TestCaller()[someArgs.methodName](someArgs.methodProps); // <-- fails at someArgs.methodProps 
}
```

Comment: This is TypeScript's inability to directly support *correlated union types* as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  If you want the compiler to "get" what you're doing, you'd need to refactor to use generics as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which would look like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wjpxYm). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (or find a suitable duplicate target).  If not, what am I missing?